# help with adding wings to model

Tags: mesh

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=LvRHFRwrIBY

I am new to blender and I want to make a custom skin for the game League of Legends.

I'm only allowed to have one mesh because the program converting the .gtlf/glb to .skn .skl (League files) only allows one mesh. Now I have this mesh and want to add wings on it that move with the mesh/bone I connected it to, like shown.

It works if the 2 meshes are not combined and it keeps it onto the character, but when I combine the meshes it suddently looses the connection to the bone, I paired it with.

I once did it and it worked, but the program crashed and I lost the process, so I know it somehow works.